# Microsoft Endpoint Protection Windows Azure 2.0

Tags: azure

I've been running Azure 1.7 for .Net in production for some time and we are using Microsoft Endpoint Protection (MEP). I've recently started the upgrade to 2.0 for Azure and as far as I can tell, the MEP plugin hasn't been upgraded for use with Azure 2.0. It only installs directly to the 1.7 sdk, not to 2.0.

It seems like I might have to wait until they upgrade it, but I'm wondering if anyone knows of any plans for this to happen? Is it no longer supported/necessary?

Also posted to MSDN at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/506b3405-b9f9-461c-b0f3-3dfce791beda/microsoft-endpoint-protection-windows-azure-20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today there are no publicly announced plans on working with this plugin.

However there is very fresh announcement about cooperation between Microsoft and Barracuda software on providing internet security for Windows Azure Services. You may want to check more on the following links:

- [Barracuda on Windows Azure](https://www.barracuda.com/programs/azure)
- [Deploying Barracude Web Application Firewall on Azure](http://techlib.barracuda.com/display/BWAFv76/Deploying+the+Barracuda+Web+Application+Firewall+Vx+-+Windows+Azure)
- [Security-as-a-Service provided by Barracuda](https://www.barracuda.com/news/press_release/93)